# sql identity insert interruption

Tags: sql, sql-server

This might be an obvious question.
I have a sql sproc which runs a cursor.

The cursor will insert a certain amount of records into a table. 
The problem is that, say the cursor runs 1000 insert statements, these records identity must follow on each other.  if someone else runs an insert while the cursor is running, it will take up a record between two of the records the cursor is running.

can anyone give me some tips to ensure that all the cursor inserts follow each other.

Please note that my cursor might do 50 000 inserts. which means it will take a while to do all the inserts. so that table must not be interrupted while performing inserts.

Comment: Do you mean that the value inserted into the primary column using identity property must be sequential?

Comment: If you do more than 5000 "manipulations" to a table in a single transaction, SQL Server will **exclusively lock** the entire table through a mechanism called *lock escalation*. That means: no one can even select from that table until the transaction commits (or gets rolled back)

Comment: hi raj, yes it must be sequential, no "other" records may be inserted between those records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable WITH (TABLOCK)
...
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
i see one problem though, the insert will be inside the cursor. so basically multiple inserts on their own.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION t_Transaction

BEGIN TRY

  INSERT INTO  Table
 SELECT * 
 FROM tablx
  WITH (HOLDLOCK)


 COMMIT t_Transaction

END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK t_Transaction
END CATCH
```